# Trying to figure out why autoloader wont find my classes

Tags: php

Im trying to get my classes to be found via the autoload function...But all i get is that the autoloader cant find the classes

I have this autoload.php that contains this code

```
    <?php

function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}
?>
```

And the classes exists in the classes folder, and the autoloader is outside of this folder.

Any pointers would be nice!

Comment: It also must be registered with [spl_autoload_register function](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Use Include Inside Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121211/php-use-include-inside-function)

put the include code on the top of the file after the php tags. 
and instead of passing parameter i suggest you should put the actual name.

OR

you could create a array and use the for-loop to include the files.

but make sure they are on top.

```
<?php
$files = array("String", "CURL" , "Encryption");
foreach($files as $file){
    include 'classes/' . $file . '.php';
}
```

hope this helps.